# JMeter: Как в HTTP Request Defaults в поле path по очереди передавать данные из csv файла?

Tags: производительность, test-automation, jmeter

Как в HTTP Request Defaults в поле path по очереди передавать данные из csv файла?
Есть файл с ссылками на страници сайта экспортированный из базы данных, хочеться по очереди каждую ссылку проверить на время загрузки и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элемент [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) (ключевое слово **Defaults**) предназначен для того, чтобы задавать **общие** параметры для всех сэмплеров [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) в его [скоупе действия](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules).

Например вы можете задать хост, порт, таймауты и т.д. **только в одном месте** чтобы если, например, тестируемое приложение переедет на другой адрес вы могли его поменять в только HTTP Request Defaults без необходимости это делать для каждого HTTP Request сэмплера.

Пример использования данных из CSV файла для параметризации тестов JMeter вы можете посмотреть в темплейте `Building an Advanced Web Test Plan`:

```
File -> Templates -> Building an Advanced Web Test Plan -> Create
```

[image: JMeter ADvanced Web test Plan csv]

Comment: Принято. Но это не решает мою задачу. У меня есть адрес и куча slug в файле. Их нужно все прогнать JMeter, на каждый слаг создавать руками семпл не хочеться. Хочеться сделать автоматизированный процесс